# Writing a single large data file, or multiple smaller files: Which is faster?

Tags: c++, linux, filesystems, file-writing

I am developing a c++ program that writes a large amount of data to disk. The following function gzips the data and writes it out to a file. The compressed data is on the order of 100GB. The function to compress and write out the data is as follows:

```
 void constructSNVFastqData(string const& fname) {                                 
   ofstream fastq_gz(fname.c_str());                                           
   stringstream ss;                                                                
   for (int64_t i = 0; i < snvId->size(); i++) {                            
     consensus_pair &cns_pair = snvId->getPair(i);                                 
     string qual(cns_pair.non_mutated.size(), '!');                                
      ss << "@" + cns_pair.mutated + "[" + to_string(cns_pair.left_ohang) +         
            ";" + to_string(cns_pair.right_ohang) + "]\n" 
             + cns_pair.non_mutated + "\n+\n" + qual + "\n";                                            
   }                                                                               
   boost::iostreams::filtering_streambuf<boost::iostreams::input> out;             
   out.push(boost::iostreams::gzip_compressor());                                  
   out.push(ss);                                                                   
   boost::iostreams::copy(out,fastq_gz);                                           
   fastq_gz.close();                                                                                                 
 }
```

The function writes data to a string stream, which I then 
write out to a file (`fastq_gz`) using boost's `filtering_streambuf`. 
The file is not a log file. After the file has been written
it will be read by a child process. The file does not need to be viewed
by humans.

Currently, I am writing the data out to a single, large file (`fastq_gz`). This is taking a while, and the file system - according to our system manager - is very busy. I wonder if, instead of writing out a single large file, I should instead write out a number of smaller files? Would this approach be faster, or reduce the load on the file system?

Please note that it is not the compression that is slow - I have benchmarked.

I am running on a linux system and do not need to consider generalising the implementation to a windows filesystem.

Comment: Have you looked into log rotation? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log_rotation

Comment: I recommend splitting into smaller files because viewing 100GB may be difficult with applications.

Comment: Have you profiled, where your bottleneck is? I'm guessing that the disk I/O is simply saturated, so regardless of what you do, you are already doing it as fast as the system allows you to.

Comment: @Magnus Do you have any links for parallelizing the write IO in C++? I though this approach was not a good design, due to access to the file system being mutually exclusive, and therefore, their ends up being a huge amount of lock contention.

Comment: Also, I suggest creating a separate thread that writes the data, if possible.  For example, main thread writes to a buffer.  The writing thread moves from buffer to a file.

Comment: What kind of data does that large file contains (textual or binary) ? How would it be accessed?

Comment: Technically, you can't parallelize file I/O.  Most hard drives are serial I/O and process one transaction at a time.  If you want to parallel file writing, use multiple hard drives.  Hard drives like streaming data, from only one source at a time.

Comment: Ok. I will add more information. Let me edit.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews: Why would that be any faster? If anything, it increases pressure on the memory, eventually causing memory to get swapped to disk. Now everything is slower.

Comment: @IInspectable:  The idea is to have a dedicated thread that is continuously writing to the hard drive.  For example, the thread could write a huge buffer to the drive, and while the hardware is transferring the data, the main thread can be executing.  May reduce workload on the system by allowing the OS to swap out threads.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews: Why would running two threads reduce the workload compared to running a single thread? That really doesn't make a lot of sense. The data is already there. It just needs to be dumped to disk. Adding threads will only increase overall system workload, not reduce it.

Comment: For ultimate efficiency, the "writing thread" could be set up as an ISR, so that when the data is finished writing to the drive, the writing device activates and interrupt, which calls the "writing thread".  This is a similar algorithm used by embedded systems to write to serial ports.

Comment: Another benefit of the "writing thread" is that the system is not locked up.  The main function can still run, performing other activities.

Comment: Is your program under any time constraints to write the data safely to disk? "faster" and "less load on the filesystem" are usually incompatible.

Comment: Is the disk SSD?  Multiple drives that are striped? Does `iostat 5` show that the disk throughput is leveling off at a certain speed?

Comment: @ThomasMatthews: The system does not lock up, when one process' thread is busy writing to disk. Setting up an ISR also will not make writing to disk any faster. Whenever I read your recommendations on performance optimizations I keep asking myself: Have you ever, in your entire career, launched a profiler?

Comment: @Mark Plotnick Unfortunately I cannot determine whether the disk is SSD (almost certainly this is not the case). I am running on my universities super computer, and I have very limit access to filesystem knowledge; I cannot run `iostat 5` unfortunately.

Comment: Their are no time constraints - other than impatience. The program cannot do anything until the data has been written, the child process called, and the output of the child process read by the parent. So, a design that spawns a writing thread, freeing the program to perform other tasks is not necessary.

Comment: The answer is probably "work with the people who have to maintain the system and who have the ability to benchmark it". A disk may have multiple physical spindles, so it may tolerate multiple write operations simultaneously without hurting performance, which means you can write multiple files - or different regions of the same file - in parallel.

Comment: As @ThomasMatthews explained, my understanding is also that true I/O parallelism is not possible. I just wondered if I was missing something obvious related to file system structure that I could exploit - for example, if the initial block contained a table of all other block's locations (which could get updated heavily if the blocks become too numerous). It appears their is no easy solution :(

Comment: @MarkPlotnick, OK. Thank you. Thanks for your advice All.

Answer (score 0):

So what your code is probably doing is (a) generating your file into memory swap space, (b) loading from swap space and compressing on the fly, (c) writing compressed data as you get it to the outfile.

(b) and (c) are great; (a) is going to kill you.  It is two roundmtrips of thr uncompressed data, one of which while competing with your output file generation.

I cannot find one in boost iostreams, but you need an istream (source) or a device that gets data from you on demand.  Someone must have written it (it seems so useful), but I don't see it in 5 minutes of looking at boost iostreams docs.

Answer (score -2):

0.) Devise an algorithm to divide the data into multiple files so that it could be recombined later.
1.) Write data to multiple files on separate threads in the background. Maybe shared threads. (maybe start n = 10 threads at a time or so) 
2.) Query through the future attribute of the shared objects to check if writing is done. (size > 1 GB)
3.) Once above is the case; then recombine data when it is queried by the child process
4.) I would recommend writing a new file after every 1 GB

Comment: Why are people obsessed with the idea, that spreading disk writes across different threads would increase the overall I/O throughput? Sorry, this is not helpful, at all.

Comment: The bottleneck is I/O throughput, not anything else. Trying to spread I/O reading/writing among threads is wrong on so many levels...